# linking form submission to smart contract

Tags: solidity, remix, ganache, gui, eth-call

I have a smart contract that sends x ether to an address. 
I have an html page that has a form for the address, and the amount to be sent. Theoretically it should interface with the smart contract.
Nothing happens when i submit the form. It doesn't work on remix or ganache.
On my form, do i have to specify a form action as i would in html? Would the contract not do that?

The html file is similar to https://github.com/dappuniversity/20_minute_dapp/blob/master/index.html 
but the forms/variables are changed and all the css and formatting is removed.

my sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.11;


contract ReceiveEther {

uint256 public count;

function () external payable {
    require(count < 2);
    count++;
}


function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
    return address(this).balance;

}
}

contract SendEther {
    function sendViaCall (address payable _to) public payable {
        (bool sent, bytes memory data) = _to.call.value(msg.value)("");
        require (sent, "failed to send ether");
    }
}
```

My html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <body>
            <h1 >send ___ ether to ___ </h1>
          <br/>

          <!-- in html/php i have to say what is executed on form submit (usually a php action).
          Since the smart contract is doing it, do i need to specify anything here or can i do 
it down below? -->

          <form role="form">
            <label for="Receiver">Receiver:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="receiver" name="receiver" ><br>
            <label for="lname">amount in eth:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" >
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"
          </form>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/web3.min.js"></script>
    <script>

      // Starting Web3
      if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
      } else {
        web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545'));
      }

      // stating account
      web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];


// Stating Contract Abi
      var contractAbi = [WHATEVER THE ABI IS ];

      // Stating Contract Address
      var contractAddress = 'WHATEVER THE ADDRESS IS';

      // matching abi to contract
      var contract = web3.eth.contract(contractAbi).at(contractAddress);

      // action on submit
      $('form').on('submit', function(sendViaCall) {
        contract.sendViaCall($('input').val());
      })

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I feel the issue is related to the submission, but what do I know. 
Thank you for any guidance

Answer (score 0):

Note, the DappUniversity tutorials require Ganache or ganache-cli local blockchain running.

Web3js is trying to connect to the local blockchain on this line:

```
 web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545'));
```

Go ahead and download Ganache [here](https://www.trufflesuite.com/ganache). You will also need to specify contractAddress & contractAbi. Ganache will give you several dummy accounts funded with fake ETH you can use for testing.

Comment: I understand, and I have been doing this with Ganache. However, it is still not working. I have been entering the appropriate ABI and address when running the program, but did not post it in the example.